# Performing mathematical operations on values from two dictionaries with same keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries named as, lets say, `a = {'A':{2021:45.65},'B':{2021:56.34}}` and `b = {'A':{2021:78.67},'B':{2021:87.54}}`

I want to get the values from both A and B 'sub-dictionaries' and compute what percentage of value from the second dictionary is the value from the first dictionary.

I can't seem to figure out a way how to access both the float values from different dictionaries and compute the result.

--------------------------**UPDATE**------------------------

Apologies about not comprehending my problem in a proper manner. I figured out a way to do that and if you think it has an issue still please do mention.

```
dict_keys = ['A','B']
for x in dict_keys:
   val1 = a[x].values()
   val2 = b[x].values()
```

Comment: Okay, what is your question about this? Was there a particular problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: Write a tentative code, if it gives an error, then post it

Comment: Break the problem down into steps and go from there. Are you able to get the values from the sub-dictionaries? Are you able to compare the two sets? Try writing some code to accomplish each step

Comment: You might also post an example of what you are trying to do... "compute what percentage of value from the second dictionary is the value from the first dictionary" is ambiguous.

Comment: The percentage thing, I meant it like what percentage of 78.67 is 45.65

Comment: `a['A'][2021]` should get your results from `a = {'A':{2021:'...'}}` and likewise from the others.

Comment: first try to do it for every element separated - like `a["A"][2021] / b["A"][2021]` - and later see if there is pattern in code so you could use ie. `for`-loop to make it simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned in some of the comments breaking this into logical parts/steps can help a lot.

```
//pseudocode
if the len of a == len of b:
    for key, value in a:
        if the len of a[key] == len of b[key]:
            for key, value in a[key]:
                more_less = a's key's value divided by b's key's value
```

---

Proper code for anyone Googling their way here:

```
#  [partially] confirming data integrity - you can do more here if needed
lf len(a) == len(b):
    #  iterate through each dictionary in `a` to compare to the associated dictionary in `b`
    for key, value in a:
        #  [partially] confirming data integrity of the 'child' dictionaries
        if len(value) == len(b[key]):
            for key2, value2 in a[key]:
                #  key2 is, in this case, '2021'; value2 is the number
                more_less = value2 / b[key][key2]
                #  We'll print the result here, you can also use string formatting, of course, but to keep it as the most basic level:
                print(str(b[key][key2]) + " is " + str(more_less) + "% of " + value2 + ".")
```

Comment: I figured out a way to do that and since I have a very simple data and I am simply computing a numerical value from the structures, I think it will according to my needs. But your approach also seems reasonable. I'll keep that in my mind next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if you guarantee the structure of the dicts are exactly the same for a and b you can simply traverse one and use the key to access the other, but this is rather weak of an approach.

```
result = {}  
for key, item in a.items():  
    for nest_key, nest_item in a[key].items():
        result[key] = nest_item / b[key][nest_key]
```